# Pseudo randomization constraints

Tags: psychopy

I am programming a task switching experiment with 3 tasks. The aim of the experiment is to investigate sequential effects: triplets in which the task X repeat after a switch (e.g. ABA or CAC) will be compared with triplets in which the task always switch (e.g. CBA or BAC).

To this aim, is important that the 3 tasks never repeat and that in each block there are (roughly) the same number of repeat and switch sequences.

Each block has 108 trials resulting in 106 triplets (the first two trials cannot be classified as repeat or switch of course).

I have tried to find a solution with several softwares (Psychopy, Conan, Excel), but I haven't found a solution, and I have no clue how to do it.

Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

There are only six possible orders in which the task doesn't repeat:

```
A   B   C
A   C   B
B   A   C
B   C   A
C   A   B
C   B   A
```

And six where it does:

```
A   B   A
A   C   A
B   A   B
B   C   B
C   A   C
C   B   C
```

So to get to 108 trials, you just need to present each of those orders nine times. But this might conflict with your requirement that the tasks don't repeat (but that phrasing is ambiguous and you should be more specific as to the meaning of that constraint.)

Also, phrases like "there are (roughly) the same number of repeat and switch sequences" aren't great when defining an experimental design. Strive for as much precision as possible.

Having said all that, I'm not sure how this is yet an actual programming-related question? You'll need to say exactly what the issue is with implementing this. The programs you mention have wildly different purposes (PsychoPy is for implementing experiments. Excel is not. I don't know what Conan is).

Comment: Yes, those are the possible sequences. Now I come to your points. My question relates exactly how to respect my constraints: how can I make Psychpy generating a list of those 3 values, each repeated 36 times, without any value repetition? On top of that, how can I make sure that those 18 triplets are repeated the same amount of time each? Notice that each trial is the end of a triplet, and therefore they are not independent. For example a sequence of trial: A-B-C-A-B will result in a ABC, a BCA and a CAB sequence.

Comment: Your first task is simply to express your desired experimental design in precise and unambiguous prose. That generally makes it straightforward to turn into an algorithm. With descriptions like "a list of those 3 values, each repeated 36 times, without any value repetition", perhaps you can see how that might currently be challenging for someone else to get to grips with. I'd suggest you take this to the PsychoPy forum at https://discourse.psychopy.org, as this is currently very far from yet being a SO-suitable programming question.